# Google distance matrix API Info window

Tags: android, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

How to create such a info windows using google distance matrix API in Android? Should I consume json response?
[image]

Comment: Isnt this just using Google's distance API, adding a polyline and then adding info to the polyline's infoWindow? I believe that's how you do it

Answer (score 0):

[Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) is a service that provides travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations, based on the recommended route between start and end points.

So if you want to place info window, you need to use another API which is [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

An [`InfoWindow`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#introduction) displays content (usually text or images) in a popup window above the map, at a given location. The info window has a content area and a tapered stem. The tip of the stem is attached to a specified location on the map.

The `InfoWindow` constructor takes an `InfoWindowOptions` object literal, which specifies the initial parameters for displaying the info window.

The `InfoWindowOptions` object literal contains the following fields: `position` which ontains the `LatLng` at which this info window is anchored. Note: An `InfoWindow` may be attached either to a Marker object (in which case its position is based on the marker's location) or on the map itself at a specified `LatLng`. Opening an info window on a marker will automatically update the `position`.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247145/how-to-put-a-infowindow-on-polyline-in-google-maps-v3) for more information.