# Multiple markers with google maps API route, drawn by distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I'm creating a route on Google maps. The route has a start and endpoint with about 10 waypoints along the way.

What i'd like to do is 'walk' virtualy over this route, doing so i want to display a marker (depending on distance in meters) how far i have walked so far.

I've got it all set, the route, the distance in meters, the only thing that i cannot get to work is adding a marker ON the route.

Startpoint (0) ---------(marker 300 meter)-------------------- Endpoint (1000)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

I'm using the code as documented, here is my jscode fwiw

```
// I'm getting a startpoint (stockholm) endpoint (italy) and 
// array of 10 waypoints of other places in europe along the way

function initMap(startCoordinate, endCoordinate, waypoints) {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 50.60, lng: 8.36 },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
});
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: false,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
});

var start = new google.maps.LatLng(startCoordinate);
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(endCoordinate);

directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function () {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
});

displayRoute(start, end, directionsService, directionsDisplay, waypoints);
}

function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display, waypoints) {

if (waypoints.length > 1)
{
    waypoints.shift();
    waypoints.pop();
}

service.route({
    origin: 'Centralplan 15, 111 20 Stockholm',
    destination: 'Piazza Giuseppe Garibaldi, 80142 Napoli, Italië',
    waypoints: waypoints,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    avoidTolls: true
}, function (response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        display.setDirections(response);
    } else {
        console.log('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

I have looked into http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html but this is an animation on the route, i just need a still marker. It does however place a marker on route, i cannot seem to figure out exactly how it does that.

Comment: so you know the marker coordinates and don't know how to display it ?

Comment: Hi, no i dont know the marker coordinates since the route displayed is variable. I can only get the coords of the start and endpoint. The line drawn between the two points is something the google maps library seems to do automatically

Comment: i do have the variables where the marker should be placed. That is, between point a and point b, say point a to b is 20km, and i have a variable that says 15 kilometer the marker should be placed 15 kilomter away from point a, on route to point b

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9090409/3410584

Comment: Thank you, i have seen that before, but a polyline is not the same as a route(direction). Example of route(direction) https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/Boston,+Massachusetts,+USA/New+York,+USA/@41.5368177,-73.0926148,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x89e3652d0d3d311b:0x787cbf240162e8a0!2m2!1d-71.0588801!2d42.3600825!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2m2!1d-74.0059413!2d40.7127837?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will basically need to loop through the `DirectionsLegs` of your route, then in its `DirectionsSteps` and maybe substeps (`DirectionsStep` has an array of `DirectionsSteps`) until you find one which has your point A as `start_location`.

So you will now have the equivalent of a portion of line, and will be able to do what's describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9090409/3410584).